# Distance travelled and exit point between two parallel mirrors in 3D

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, simulation

I'm the author of [open-source optical ray-tracing software](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/pvtrace). One very common problem is light bouncing between two parallel mirrors. Currently, this is very slow because I follow each ray at each bounce until it exits (i.e. point $E$ in the diagram below).

I'm trying to find an expression which lets me calculate the exit point,

$$E = (x, y, z)$$

and ray direction at the exit point,

$$\lambda = (a, b, c)$$

For example, see the diagram below is a simplification of the problem to 2D. I'm actually trying to find a **full 3D solution** for arbitrary length ($L$), width ($W$) and height ($H$), starting point ($A$) and first bounce point ($B$). All of these quantities are known. Unknowns are all other bounce points.

I have solved this iteratively, by calculating all the other bounce points by moving one step along and flipping the direction vector each time. I was hoping to gain some mathematical insight into this problem in 3D to see if there is an expression which does not require iteration.

One useful piece of information is that $\tau$, the full pathlength, is the same in the black and red line (plus distance AB).

[image: 2D simplification of problem]

Comment: The usual way to tackle such problems is to “unfold” the path, as you’ve done with the red line. Then, instead of working with the actual zigzag path, you examine the straight line’s intersections with a grid defined by successive reflections of the mirrors. Note, too, that your problem reduces to a two-dimensional one by considering only the plane of the reflected ray’s path.

Comment: @boyfarrell You have mentioned in your problem statement that the first bounce point $\bf{B}$ is known. Now, point $\bf{B}$ can be on the top or the bottom mirror. Can we assume that we know the mirror on which the point $\bf{B}$ is located?

Comment: I think it’s ok to say it will always be the top or the bottom mirror. However, in general we don’t know. But the system is symmetrical   parallel to the mirror surface, so maybe both choices will be very similar

Comment: @boyfarrell The system is not symmetrical with respect to the starting point $\bf{A}$ unless it is the midpoint of the screen placed at $x=0$. Therefore, it is not possible to derive an expression that lets you calculate the exit point $\bf{E}$ without knowing on which mirror the point $\bf{B}$ lies.   When you reply me, please begin your reply with $\bf{@YNK}$

Comment: @YNK that’s true. My intuition was that if we flip the z axis then a point on the top mirror becomes a point on the bottom mirror. However, I think it’s absolutely fine to assume that $\bf{B}$ is always on the top surface. I can use standard ray-tracing to get to the top surface and then change over to using the optimisation.